# Unity 2D. A*Path смещение по оси Z

Tags: unity3d

Для ИИ Врагов я использую бесплатную версию A* path. Но почему то когда я бегу вверх, то все бегущие за мной смещаются по оси Z и уходят из видимости. Я ранее читал на других форумах про эту проблему, но там решение одно - переустановка новой версии, но у меня итак новая версия. В настройках сетки я выставил 2D, правильные границы, в общем, вроде там всё ок.

Если проблема не решится - всё плохо. Подойдёт любая помощь.